# MVC4; How do you give google.maps.LatLng with JSON.stringify to ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, google-maps, actionresult

I have a marker on google.maps. I have the location of the marker in lat and lng. This is the markerLocation here below.

```
    $google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (a) {
        markerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(a.latLng.lat(), a.latLng.lng());
    });
```

Now i have a button. When i click on that the markerLocation must be sent to a ActionResult.

```
$(function () {
  $("#btnCheck").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Check",
        cache: false,
        data: { "data": JSON.stringify(markerLocation) },
        success: function (data) {
            //blabla
        }
    });
  });
});
```

My ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult Check(????)
    {
        Point p = new Point();
        p.X = ??;
        p.Y = ??;

        return Json(new { success = true});
    }
```

Now i want to know what must come in '????' so i can give the latitude and longitude to a X and Y of a Point.

if i set a alert:

```
    $google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (a) {
       markerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(a.latLng.lat(), a.latLng.lng());
       alert(markerLocation)
    });
```

the output is (56.234345, 23.5365325)

**UPDATE**

I changed one line of code:

```
  data: { "data": JSON.stringify({data: markerLocation}) },
```

the ouput of data is now: "{\"data\":{\"lb\":52.446463014964465,\"mb\":5.865478515625}}"
i don't know what to do next in de ActionResult Check(??)

Comment: Could you please add to your question what the output of the `JSON.stringify(markerLocation)` is?

Comment: the output is if the ActionResult is: public ActionResult Check(string data)
data = the Longitude

Comment: Oh wait, not anymore, data = null right now